# textbox autocomplete does not always work

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox

i have set autocompletemode to append for my textbox and most of the time it works fine, but there is one scenario which causes problems

expected behavior : if i input "A" textbox should append text to "ABC"

When i input "A" , auto completed "BC" appears next to it, if i now select whole "ABC" with a mouse, delete it from textbox and press A again, it would not autocompete it again.

Why is it so? and how can i fix it? Thanks

Comment: Is it work if you lost the textbox focus and set focus again?

Comment: Nope. But when i input A, "BC" appears, and i press B before selecting and deleting ABC with a mouse - it works. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score -2):

Use `listbox` instead of `textbox` to avoid this problem.